# Broken image although correct file path next.js and tailwind

Tags: html, next.js

[image]

In components >> navbar.js I have a path to image folder

```
<img
  className="block lg:hidden h-8 w-auto"
  src='../images/logo_injoy.png'
  alt="Logo"
/>
```

Image comes out broken. If I put the image in the root folder however, it will showcase

```
<img
 className="block lg:hidden h-8 w-auto"
 src='../logo_injoy.png'
 alt="Logo"
/>
```

Comment: And `/images/logo_injoy.png` ?

Comment: unfortunately not

Comment: Are you sure that this folder is include as assets ?

Comment: it's a next.js app, no need for assets here. It find's it is I use next.js Image component, just doesn't with tailwind image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To serve files like that you need to either import them or put them in `public` folder:

```js
// This will only work with Next.js v11+
// -- For previous versions you need to use file-loader

import Logo from '../images/logo_injoy.png';

<img className="block lg:hidden h-8 w-auto" src={Logo.src} alt="Logo" />
```

or if `logo_injoy.png` is inside `public/images` then:

```js
<img className="..." src="/images/logo_injoy.png" alt="Logo" />
```

Refer: [Static File Serving](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving)